# How to get list of directories containing particular file using c#

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I wish to get list of all the folders/directories that has a particular file in it. How do I do this using C# code.

Eg: Consider I have 20 folders of which 7 of them have a file named "abc.txt". I wish to know all folders that has the file "abc.txt".

I know that we can do this by looking thru all the folders in the path and for each check if the File.Exists(filename); But I wish to know if there is any other way of doing the same rather than looping through all the folder (which may me little time consuming in the case when there are many folders).

Thanks
-Nayan

Comment: You have to do it Recursively as far as I'm aware I'm afraid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use the method [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) of the Directory class with a search pattern and the SearchOption to include AllDirectories. This will return all files (full filename including directory) that match the pattern.

Using the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) class you get the directory of the file.

```
string rootDirectory = //your root directory;
var foundFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootDirectory , "abc.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var file in foundFiles){
  Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
}
```

EnumerateFiles is only available since .NET Framework 4. If you are working with an older version of the .NET Framework then you could use [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) of the Directory class.

Update (see comment from PLB):

The code above will fail if the access to a directory in denied. In this case you will need to search each directory one after one to handle exceptions.

```
public static void SearchFilesRecursivAndPrintOut(string root, string pattern)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(root);
    try
    {
        var childDireactory = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root);
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, pattern);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
        }

        foreach (var dir in childDireactory)
        {
            SearchRecursiv(dir, pattern);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: One drawback of this aproach is that it will throw `UnauthorizedAccessException` if at least one sub-folder is inaccessible.

Comment: @Jehof - This approach did not work.. I tried the same.. EnumerateFiles returns me empty list :( I am using .NET 4

Comment: @NayanSoni: then no file is found. or your search pattern is incorrect or you are searching the wrong directory.

Comment: @Jehof You're welcome. Generally I use recursive scan and mute these exceptions. It took `00:00:20.8214437` to scan my C drive (~400K files) with search pattern `*`.

Comment: This is definitely the right approach. If it doesn't work, you're doing it wrong. ;)

Comment: @Jehof - I am really sorry for the confusion.. Your approach worked perfectly fine.. i made a mistake of using SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly instead of AllDirectories.

Comment: @NayanSoni: Nice that it works now. I have added a recursive method to search for files, to handle the case of an exception. see also PLBs comment

Comment: @Jehof Would not it be better to surround with try/catch only recursive call? Your code will mute exception if root directory is inaccessible.

Comment: @PLB may be. i have tested the method in LinqPad on directory C:\Users\ with a search pattern "*.jpg" and it works. You can correct the method if its wrong. This was only a fast solution to update my answer

Comment: @Jehof Sure, I understand that. There's nothing wrong with code. My comment is mostly for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to narrow down your search by specific criteria (i.e. include only DLLs that contain "Microsoft", "IBM" or "nHibernate" in its name).

```
var filez = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\MLBWRT", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(
            s => s.ToLower().Contains("microsoft")
            && s.ToLower().Contains("ibm")
            && s.ToLower().Contains("nhibernate"));
string[] allFiles = filez.ToArray<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.Length; i++) {
    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(allFiles[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(fInfo.Name);
}
```

Comment: you should use `EnumerateFiles` as you're adding a where clause it your search, also this will look for file that contain "microsoft" and "ibm" and "nhibernate" you might want to change that.