# Directory.EnumerateDirectories : Only get back Directores with a special file in it

Tags: c#

I want to create list of Directories on an hard disk where a special file is in. (e.g. new.txt). Is this possible with Directory.EnumerateDirectories ?
Thanks and regards
Kevin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724745/how-to-get-list-of-directories-containing-particular-file-using-c-sharp

Comment: I want a lot of things to, but I cannot get them without trying myself. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service unfortunately. What exactly have you tried? Post your code and any exceptions you might have.